# How to setup an AWS CloudWatch event rule to trigger on multiple Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions

I want to be able to setup an AWS CloudWatch event rule that will trigger to an SNS topic whenever one of my Step Functions completes (either success or failure). I do not want this to run for all Step Functions, but there will be an indeterminate number of them based on a common name prefix. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this, but it appears that wildcards are not allowed in Event Patterns. Are there any creative ways to work around this?

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.states"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Step Functions Execution Status Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "status": [
      "FAILED",
      "SUCCEEDED"
    ],
    "stateMachineArn": [
      "arn:aws:states:us-west-1:123456789012:stateMachine:Prefix-*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are not supported in Cloudwatch event rule according to [AWS official forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230927).

You will have to add all the arn's in the state machine ARN list. To do it easily you may write a script that does the following:

- Get all the state machine names with specific prefix.
- Update the Cloudwatch Event Rule to include all the state machine arn's with specific prefix.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is below:

```
    {
      "source": ["aws.states"],
      "detail-type": ["Step Functions Execution Status Change"],
      "detail": {
        "status": ["SUCCEEDED", "FAILED"],
        "stateMachineArn": [ { "prefix": "arn:aws:states::us-west-1:123456789012:stateMachine:prefix-" } ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).